# “An idiom for looking foolish because of embarrassment of being unable to get what you purposed or desired”

Tags: meaning, idioms, idiom-requests

One day a girl proposed her beloved in an assembly to marry, but the beloved didn’t give her his heart, and therefore she felt embarrassed and looked foolish and went back because of failing to get what she has been desiring for ages.

Example:

> Having looked in the mirror, she felt to be **at a loss**.
>   So much pride her Lordship had on not giving the heart!

Dose “**at a loss**” somewhat suit the example ? If not, then the idiom is needed as expressed in the Title box.

Comment: I think she would feel **humiliated** at being publicly rejected!

Comment: So, does “At a loss” not suit?

Comment: A dictionary will tell you what "at a loss" means. It doesn't seem to exactly match what you suggest, but not knowing what to say or do could be a consequence of feeling embarrassed and foolish. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-at-a-loss

Comment: Stuart F,  Good! If it means not knowing ‘what to say’/ ‘what to do’ could be a consequence of feeling embarrassed and foolish, then I have got the answer to my question to some extent in the Comment box.

Comment: Stuart F, at a loss indicates she was embarrassed and helpless and unable to understand what to do if he didn’t give his heart to her

Answer (score 4):

A good word to describe this feeling is ***crestfallen***, which describes an intense disappointment that comes after having high hopes. It connotes the expectation or strong desire for a positive outcome, and having those hopes dashed. One would not be crestfallen over not winning the lottery (since it’s so unlikely in the first place), but it fits perfectly for an intense, personal disappointment that comes as a surprise. It doesn't quite capture the feeling of embarrassment, but it is a strong disappointment that's often mixed with shock or surprise.

Answer (score 1):

Related words and idioms:

Mortified - feeling or showing strong shame or embarrassment.

(to) Lose face - suffer a loss of respect; be humiliated.

Egg on (one's) face - look stupid because of something that you have done.
Example: "She had **egg on her face** after **sticking her neck out** at the school assembly and proposing to her crush who did not requite her love.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential word:

**Chagrin** (noun, verb) - annoyance or distress at having failed or been humiliated.

M-W notes that it comes from French, in which it means "grief" or "sorroow".